# multiple str_replace functions within the same mutate()

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

my dummy code:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
y <- c("<0.5", "~1", "<10", "~30")

df <- data.frame(x,y) %>%
  mutate(y1 = str_replace(y, "~", ""),
         y2 = as.numeric(str_replace(y1, "<", ""))/2)
```

Basically what I want to do in column y is:

- Remove the "~" from values that contain "~"
- Remove "<" from values that contain "<", then halve those values

Ideally I'll come out with a fully numeric column.

How do I go about this step without needing the interim "y1" variable? I've tried putting both into str_replace but doesn't seem to work, or creates NAs. I've also tried piping within the str_replace but that doesn't work either. Note I only want the "<" values halved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can concatenate several remove conditions by the OR operator:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 y = c("<0.5", "~1", "<10", "~30"))

df %>%
  mutate(y2 = as.numeric(str_remove(y, "<|~")),
         y2 = if_else(str_detect(y, '<'), 0.5 * y2, y2))
```

which gives:

```
  x    y    y2
1 A <0.5  0.25
2 B   ~1  1.00
3 C  <10  5.00
4 D  ~30 30.00
```

Updated solution by overwriting y:

```
df %>%
  mutate(y = if_else(str_detect(y, '<'), 0.5 * as.numeric(str_remove(y, "<|~")), as.numeric(str_remove(y, "<|~"))))
```

which gives:

```
  x     y
1 A  0.25
2 B  1.00
3 C  5.00
4 D 30.00
```

Of course you could also just delete the old y column from solution 1 and rename y2 to y.

Comment: unfortunately I only need the values which contain "<" to be halved, not the ones with the "~". is there a workaround for this?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you, works perfectly. out of curiosity, why does the second line in the mutate detect the "<", if we removed it in the first line?

Comment: Pay close attention to which variable I feed to the str_detect! I pass y, not y2.

Comment: i have one last question. ideally i would like to be able to overwrite the 'y' column, instead of creating 'y2'. is there any easy way to do this concisely? thanks.

Comment: See updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Update: See comment of op:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(str_detect(y, "<"), parse_number(y)/2, parse_number(y)))
```

```
  x     y
1 A  0.25
2 B  1.00
3 C  5.00
4 D 30.00
```

@deschen answer is good. An alternative is to use `parse_number` from `readr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(y2 = ifelse(str_detect(y, "<"), parse_number(y)/2, parse_number(y)))
```

```
  x    y    y2
1 A <0.5  0.25
2 B   ~1  1.00
3 C  <10  5.00
4 D  ~30 30.00
```

Comment: thanks for this. ideally i would like to be able to overwrite the 'y' column, instead of creating 'y2'. is there any easy way to do this concisely? thanks.

Comment: Please see my update!